# Squid source code directory renaming gives "aclocal-1.14" missing error during make clean

Tags: linux, directory, makefile, rename, squid

I have a squid source code dir, which works fine for `./configure && make clean` as below

```
cd /opt/squid-3.5.4
./configure && make clean
```

now when I create a copy of the dir & try to do `./configure && make clean`, I get an error

```
cp -r /opt/squid-3.5.4 /opt/squid-3.5.4_BKUP
cd /opt/squid-3.5.4_BKUP
./configure && make clean
.....
.....
.....
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/squid-3.5.4_BKUP/lib'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/squid-3.5.4_BKUP/lib'
Making clean in libltdl
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/squid-3.5.4_BKUP/libltdl'
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/sh /opt/squid-3.5.4_BKUP/libltdl/config/missing aclocal-1.14 -I m4
/opt/squid-3.5.4_BKUP/libltdl/config/missing: line 81: aclocal-1.14: command not found
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.14' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
make[1]: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/squid-3.5.4_BKUP/libltdl'
make: *** [clean-recursive] Error 1
```

Machine details:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
aclocal --version
aclocal (GNU automake) 1.11.1
```

It says `aclocal-1.14` is missing, but in dir `/opt/squid-3.5.4` it works fine with current aclocal version.

Could somebody tell me how can build (/make) in renamed dir

PS: After some google search, I've tried doing below

```
cd /opt/squid-3.5.4_BKUP
touch configure.ac aclocal.m4 configure Makefile.am Makefile.in
autoreconf -ivf
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

looks like i had to do:

```
cd /opt/squid-3.5.4_BKUP/libltdl/
touch configure.ac aclocal.m4 configure Makefile.am Makefile.in
```